# Geopy to shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, ogr, geopy

Trying to use the latitude and longitude that is returned by geopy to create a shapefile. The shapefile creator part works line if I give it a set of numbers (44.977753, -93.2650108) but it will not work with the returned data lat_long. My thought is that it needs a "," but I dont know.

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
import csv
import ogr, os
def geopy(): 

    loc = raw_input("What location? ")
    geolocator =  GoogleV3()
    location = geolocator.geocode(loc, exactly_one=True) 
    if location != None:
        Address = location.address
        lat_long = location.latitude, location.longitude
        latitude = str(location.latitude)
        longitude = str(location.longitude)  
        print Address, latitude, longitude
        print""


    else:
        print "There is no geographic information to return for the word in input. \n"    

# Input data
    pointCoord = lat_long
    fieldName = 'test'
    fieldType = ogr.OFTString
    fieldValue = 'test'
    outSHPfn = "output file"
# create the spatial reference, WGS84
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

# Create the output shapefile
    shpDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    if os.path.exists(outSHPfn):
        shpDriver.DeleteDataSource(outSHPfn)
    outDataSource = shpDriver.CreateDataSource(outSHPfn)
    outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer(outSHPfn, srs, geom_type = ogr.wkbPoint )

#create point geometry
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(pointCoord[0],pointCoord[1])

# create a field
    idField = ogr.FieldDefn(fieldName, fieldType)
    outLayer.CreateField(idField)

# Create the feature and set values
    featureDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
    outFeature.SetGeometry(point)
    outFeature.SetField(fieldName, fieldValue)
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)    

geopy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a loop to put the latitude and longitude in a list. This code will create a point shapefile of any location you give it.

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
import csv
import ogr, os

def geopy(location):
    """This function takes the word given about 
    and uses GoogleV3 to search for a location. If a 
    location is found it then returns the Address, latitude and longitude.
    It then prints that information to a .CSV"""

    geolocator =  GoogleV3()
    loc_input = raw_input("Add the location you would like data back for: ")
    location = geolocator.geocode(loc_input, exactly_one=True) 
    if location != None:
         Address = location.address
         lat_lon = location.latitude, location.longitude
         latitude = str(location.latitude)
         longitude = str(location.longitude)  
         print Address, latitude, longitude
         print""


        #Converts lat_long to a list for use in making the shapefile.
        list_lat = []
        for i in range(1):
             list_lat.append(lat_lon)
        for list_of_lat_lon in list_lat:
            print""   


    #Calls list_of_lat_lon for the shapefile function 
        shapefile(list_of_lat_lon)

# If there is no location data to return it prints the below line and does not create a shapefile
    else:
        print "There is no geographic information to return for the word in input. \n"    





def shapefile(list_of_lat_lon):
"""This function uses the GDAL to return a ESRi shapefile
it uses the latitude and longitude in the list_of_lat_lon list. 
"""


    # Input data
    pointCoord = list_of_lat_lon
    fieldName = 'Lat'
    fieldType = ogr.OFTString
    fieldValue = 'test'
    outSHPfn = "Input file location"

    # create the spatial reference, WGS84
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)


    # Create the output shapefile
    shpDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")

    if os.path.exists(outSHPfn):
        shpDriver.DeleteDataSource(outSHPfn)
    outDataSource = shpDriver.CreateDataSource(outSHPfn)
    outLayer = outDataSource.CreateLayer(outSHPfn, srs, geom_type = ogr.wkbPoint )

    #create point geometry longitude first then latitude
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(pointCoord[1],pointCoord[0])

    # create a field
    idField = ogr.FieldDefn(fieldName, fieldType)
    outLayer.CreateField(idField)

    # Create the feature and set values
    featureDefn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn()
    outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
    outFeature.SetGeometry(point)
    outFeature.SetField(fieldName, fieldValue)
    outLayer.CreateFeature(outFeature)    


geopy(location)
```